# Capturing new requests in a HTML page

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How can I capture a new request (e.g. link click, page refresh, etc.) in an html page?

Let's say I need to do some stuff when user decides to go to another page or refresh the current page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the the [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) and [`window.onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload) events

You can also capture any link clinks easily [jQuery sample]:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
     // do your stuff

     // follow the link
     window.location.href = this.href;
});
```

Comment: It does not cover e.g. `​<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​>SO</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`  case.

Comment: @Engineer probably not, but they're the only mechanisms available.

Comment: I believe that onunload is fired when the content is removed from the browser context which doesn't fulfill my needs. onbeforeunload seems good and even include link clicks. Tanks